# Hilt injection works in Android Compose app but not in instrumented tests when ViewModel is passed in as argument of composable

Tags: android, kotlin, testing, android-jetpack-compose, dagger-hilt

Given this ViewModel:

```
class PrimaryViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val jokeRepository: JokeRepository
) : ViewModel() {
    ...
}
```

the following works in the production code **and** in instrumented tests:

```
import androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.compose.viewModel
...
@Composable
fun PrimaryScreen() {
    val viewModel: PrimaryViewModel = viewModel()                // ALWAYS WORKS

    ...
}
```

but for some reason the following (what I started with and fought with for two days) does not work when trying to run instrumented tests:

```
@Composable
fun PrimaryScreen(viewModel: PrimaryViewModel = viewModel()) {    // DOES NOT ALWAYS WORK
    ...
}
```

And to be complete, here is the hilt and test setup:

```
// app/src/androidTest/java/com/example/jokes/testdi/TestDataModule.kt
@Module
@TestInstallIn(
    components = [SingletonComponent::class],
    replaces = [DataModule::class]
)
interface FakeDataModule {

    @Binds
    fun bindRepository(
        fakeRepository: FakeJokeRepository
    ): JokeRepository
...
}

// app/src/androidTest/java/com/example/jokes/PrimaryScreenTest.kt
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
@HiltAndroidTest
class PrimaryScreenTest {

    var hiltRule = HiltAndroidRule(this)
    val composeTestRule = createAndroidComposeRule<MainActivity>()

    @get:Rule
    val rule: RuleChain = RuleChain
        .outerRule(hiltRule)
        .around(composeTestRule)

    @Before
    fun setup() {
        hiltRule.inject()
        composeTestRule.activity.setContent {
            PrimaryScreen()
        }
    }
```

The error is:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class com.example.jokes.ui.joke.PrimaryViewModel
    ...
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.example.jokes.ui.joke.PrimaryViewModel.<init> []
```

So rather than provide what doesn't work and then answer my own question with what does work... can anyone explain - if the hilt dependency injection while passing the ViewModel as an argument to the composable works just fine in the production code, why doesn't it work in androidTest?

---

EDIT:

Coming back to this - here a few months later - the code I have above is actually working for me now. And I believe originally when I saw the issue I was trying to use:

- `ComponentActivity` instead of `MainActivity`
- `composeTestRule.setContent` instead of `composeTestRule.activity.setContent`
  like this:

```
// Original failing state of the code
val composeTestRule = createAndroidComposeRule<ComponentActivity>()

...

// Original failing state (notice the `.activity.` is removed)
composeTestRule.setContent { 
    PrimaryScreen()
}
```

I believe this code (trying to use `ComponentActivity` instead of my `MainActivity`) may have actually been the original problematic code, and perhaps someone out there understands the nuanced differences here and why they matter.

Answer (score -1):

You need to do a @BindView with PrimaryViewModel:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
@HiltAndroidTest
class PrimaryScreenTest {

    var hiltRule = HiltAndroidRule(this)
    val composeTestRule = createAndroidComposeRule<MainActivity>()

    @get:Rule
    val rule: RuleChain = RuleChain
        .outerRule(hiltRule)
        .around(composeTestRule)

    @BindValue
    val viewModel: PrimaryViewModel = mock()

    @Before
    fun setup() {
        hiltRule.inject()
        composeTestRule.activity.setContent {
            PrimaryScreen()
        }
    }
```

Comment: I see you put `mock()` which I take to mean we would instantiate something like `FakePrimaryViewModel` (which would assume that `PrimaryViewModel` is an interface, not a concrete class). But what if I want to inject my concrete class because I'm ok with testing the real view model (let's call it `DefaultPrimaryViewModel`)? Am I misunderstanding something? Perhaps if you've left something implied you could add details to your answer to remove any ambiguity?

Comment: Additionally, I'd be happy to accept your answer if it works and if you could provide details about what it's doing and why it works, etc.

Comment: Also notice I just edited my original question with some significant new information I just learned.